# how to protect wordpress content from crawler

Tags: security

I found current wordpress content is very vulunerable to HTML cralwer like BeautifulSoup. How to protect contents?

- hide media link
- hide post content
- using ajax

These are my initial thoughts but I don't find relevant solutions. Thank you.

Comment: This isn't something unique to WP and the solutions to somebody crawling your website aren't either

Answer (score 0):

The one I use a lot is Defender Pro by WPMUDEV but its not a cheap solution.

https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/wp-defender/